# react native upload image to api got network error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data

hello i am trying to upload image to api using form-data but i am getting Network error

why i am getting this error i try to put image type manually but still not working from post man it work without any problem

```
 async ImageFormData() {
    const {photo} = this.state;
    console.log(photo);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', {
      uri: photo.uri,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: photo.name,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({isLoading: true}, () => {
        this.uploadImage(formData);
      });
    }, 100);
  }

  async uploadImage(formData) {
    console.log(formData);
    const {cid, email, phone, name} = this.state;
    console.log(cid, email, phone, name);
    fetch(
      'api,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: formData,
      },
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.info();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

TypeError: Network request failed
    at EventTarget.xhr.onerror (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389)
    at C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:502
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425)
    at C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112
    at MessageQueue.__guard (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (C:\feras\worker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111)